# What are examples how to use Email::Stuff?

Tags: perl, email

I have read about [Email::Stuff](http://p3rl.org/Email::Stuff) and came across some of the example on the net. All the examples then haven't created the object. They straight go away like this:

```
Email::Stuff->to('Simon Cozens<simon@somewhere.jp>')
            ->from('Santa@northpole.org')
            ->text_body("You've been a good boy this year. No coal for you.")
            ->attach_file('choochoo.gif')
            ->send;
```

When I follow the above method I get the error `Can't locate object method "to" via package "Email::Stuff" (perhaps you forgot to load "Email::Stuff"?) at ./test.pl line 27.` Can anyone give examples how to use Email::Stuff?

Comment: This is the error which I got ,

"Can't locate object method "to" via package "Email::Stuff" (perhaps you forgot to load "Email::Stuff"?) at ./test.pl line 27."

Comment: Well maybe you forgot to load "Email::Stuff"?

Comment: Please post the smallest, complete code that reproduces your symptoms -- code that we could run -- including `use` or `require` directives.  (Your error message **very strongly** suggests that you forgot to `use Email::Stuff;` despite your assertion to the contrary in a comment to David's answer.)

Answer (score 3):

As with all Perl modules, you have to `use` them.

```
use Email::Stuff;
```

Comment: Do you have the module installed?

Comment: That would error with *Can't locate Email/Stuff.pm in @INC* rather than *Can't locate object method*.